# Update BO in multiple table using CDS view and BOPF

Tags: abap, cds

I am trying to update data in multiple table using BOPF-CDS View.
following are the cds annotation to update in one table.
Can you guys tell me what should i change in this code to update data in multi table.

```
@ObjectModel:{
    modelCategory: #BUSINESS_OBJECT,
    compositionRoot: true,
    transactionalProcessingEnabled: true,
    createEnabled: true,
    updateEnabled: true,
    deleteEnabled: true,
    writeActivePersistence: 'ZOFT_FLIGHT_MEAL'    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- Get rid of your writeActivePersistence Annotation, and implement your own logic to write to the database in the DRAFT class of your ROOT BOPF node.
- There is a BADI `/BOBF/BADI_DAC_WRITE` available that you can implement your own write logic.

Comment: Thanks Haojie, I am creating BOPF and oData service using CDS views so i can`t edit both. Could you please suggest me where and how can i edit this BADI.